# Is there any way to hide callout list from SharePoint online library

Tags: sharepoint-online

I there any way we can hide the options like share, Hide, Preview, Copy link for a document library?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowleage, there is no option to hide callout list in the SharePoint Online modern library.

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.